# Ключевые слова TRUSTED/UNTRUSTED в предложениях по созданию библиотек

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

Может кто-то подсказать, что значат ключевые слова `TRUSTED/UNTRUSTED` в SQL предложениях ниже?

Эти предложения выполняются без каких-либо проблем. Но я не нахожу описания этих ключевых слов в синтаксических диаграмах документации.

```sql
create or replace library libExample1 trusted as static
/

Library LIBEXAMPLE1 compiled

create or replace library libExample2 untrusted as static
/

Library LIBEXAMPLE2 compiled
```

<sub>Свободный перевод [TRUSTED/UNTRUSTED keyword in oracle statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60773729/6571020) от участника [@Sumant somu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10137959/sumant-somu)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/60773729/6571020

Answer (score 3):

Удалите эти ключевые слова.

---

Если ключевые слова не упомянуты в документации, а [они НЕ упомянуты](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-LIBRARY.html#GUID-F042ABC9-2BF5-4E65-9D52-216D6228B288), то они неподдерживаются.
Никому не нужен неподдерживаемый код в продуктивной среде.

Ради интереса, спросите разработчиков, которые написали этот код:
Почему они добавили эти ключевые слова?
Что они будут делать, если код перестанет работать и надо будет устранять ошибку?

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60775291/6571020) от участника [@thatjeffsmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1156452/thatjeffsmith)</sub>